# asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm writing an MVC application, using ASP.Net Membership for security. The application will allow multiple websites to run from the same app and database.

The websites running on the app will be completely independent from each other. The users of those sites will have access to their site only.

**If I'm using one web.config, one MVC app and one database,  can I achieve site specific security using ASP.NET membership?**

Presumably I'll only have one application key so won't be able to use that to differentiate between sites. I thought about using **Roles** but will be exposing roles to site administrators -- and don't want admins to add / configure roles for a different site to their own users.

This potential problem has only just occurred to me so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when u say same app and multiple websites, do you mean they are hosted in a single site in  different virtuals? I do not get the point "multiple websites to run from the same app ".

Comment: yes, one mvc app on a server with all relevant URLs pointing at that app

Comment: if your authentication is handled inside the front- application and the cookies is provided by that, then i do not think you can achieve this. But if your front-application is just redirecting to the other applications and those have their own authentication system, then this is possible.

Comment: is this a [Multi tenent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) mvc application?

Comment: @eranga, reading the wiki link you posted, i suppose it would be a multi tenant application --thanks, i didn't realise that the concept had been defined.

Comment: @bumble bee, not sure what the answer is to that. all i know is i want one app, one dB, and one membership implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could you have them as sub sites of the main site (with web.config setup there) and therefore, the authentication permeates through the sub-sites.

Comment: does that mean i'd have to deploy the app once per site?

Comment: Do you want one web.config containing credentials for all sites, even in separate virtual directories and physical sites?

Answer (score 0):

There is an **ApplicationName** property that the roles provider uses to filter roles on.  Try setting that property before fetching roles.

Something like this should work:

```
Roles.ApplicationName = "MyAppName";
var authorized = Roles.IsUserInRole("Some.user", "admin");
```

I haven't tried this, it is a static property and could give you weird results, so be careful.  The best way to do this would be to implement your own provider so you could do something like `Roles.IsUserInRole("some.user","admin","MyAppName")`.